# Changing YouTube iframe src using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I am building a video player page. I load an `iframe` and other videos associated with a YouTube channel using Ajax. I am trying to change the `iframe src` using the `onclick` event on a number of anchors, however the `onclick` event doesn't seem to execute given my code.

Ajax Generated HTML

```js
     
    $('.play-video').on('click',function(){
     
     $('#video-view iframe').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
     $('#video-title').text($(this).data('title'));
     $('#video-description').text($(this).data('description'));
     
     $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#video-viewer').offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vid-youtube">
      <div class="video" id="video-viewer">
      <iframe name="youtube_player" width="560" height="250" frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8VYX4jDH63c?theme=light&amp;color=red&amp;showinfo=0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 20px;">
      <h4 id="video-title">Born Depressed(take 1) - Jimquisition Intro Theme Sax Cover</h4>
      <p id="video-description">Born Depressed by Drill Queen with Live Sax</p>
      <hr>
     </div>             
     
     <div style="padding: 20px !important;">
      <div class="row videos-list">
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">   
        <div class="item active"> 
         <a href="#" style="color: #565a5c" class="play-video" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8VYX4jDH63c?autoplay=1&amp;theme=light&amp;color=red&amp;showinfo=0" data-description="Born Depressed by Drill Queen with Live Sax">                                          
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8VYX4jDH63c/mqdefault.jpg" >
          Born Depressed(Take 1) 
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">   
        <div class="item "> 
         <a href="#" style="color: #565a5c" class="play-video" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/L-rAHwcCb4k?autoplay=1&amp;theme=light&amp;color=red&amp;showinfo=0" data-description="Born Depressed by Drill Queen with Live Sax, Drums" data-title="Get Lucky - Daft Punk">                                          
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L-rAHwcCb4k/mqdefault.jpg">
          Get Lucky - Daft Punk
         </a >
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It worked for me. You just put the wrong id `#video-view iframe` , it should be `#video-viewer iframe` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.on()` works on dynamically created elements if used with the following syntax:

`$(document).on('click', '<selector>', function() {});`

```
$(document).on('click', '.play-video', function() { 
  $('#video-viewer iframe').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
  $('#video-title').text($(this).data('title'));
  $('#video-description').text($(this).data('description'));

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#video-viewer').offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```